# How to print console darts? no new lines

Tags: dart, terminal, printing, console, edit

I want to display data without adding lines, but I don't want print to increment to the right. instead of editing an existing one,
[image]
how to do like docker build result in darts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this simple code to edit the line in the terminal so it doesn't create a new line

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    stdout.write("\r");
    stdout.write("Load: ${i}");
    sleep(Duration(milliseconds: 100));
  }
  print("\nFinished");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

> stdout

```
import 'dart:io';
 
void main() {
  var i = 1;
  while (i <= 20) {
    stdout.write(i);
    stdout.write(' ');
    i++;
  }
}
```